# Can we tag every questions that requires pesak?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Not the literal flag, but a little sign e.g. ***Halachic Authority Must Be Consulted, Thank You Moderators***? Any symbol will suffice.

Comment: Or even, we can have a person that goes around to all questions and adds in these words.

Comment: I once suggested a new tag called "CYLOR" back before I had the privilege to do so and it was rejected by some mod or editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaming.SE gets lots of special features for their site.  I think a special icon that looks and sounds nicer than CYLOR would be great.

Answer (score 5):

As far as it concerns site members and specifically, the question asker, I don't know if that's necessary. I think the "halacha" tag wiki and the FAQ aught to be sufficient.

As far as it concerns one-time or occasional visitors, there already is a box on the right sidebar (visible when you're not logged in) that has the same stock disclaimer as the FAQ. I think that's enough.

Adding a specific feature for this site is unlikely to happen, and adding the disclaimer to the bottom of every halacha question (859 of them), is impractical and will just clutter up the question body.

Comment: Regarding the measures currently in use and proposed, see also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/cylor-disclaimer , http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/312/perhaps-the-community-moderators-should-enact-a-more-strict-policy-regarding-hal , and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/wanted-a-standard-way-for-a-site-to-have-a-prominent-professional-advice-discla .

Answer (score 3):

SO has (paid-for) symbols for various tags (the [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flash/info) tag has an [Adobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) logo, for example). Perhaps we can get, for our [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha), [health-safety-shmira](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-safety-shmira), and [psych-mentalhealth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psych-mentalhealth) tags, a symbol like [this one](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Caution_sign_used_on_roads_pn.svg). (I'm mentioning this not because I think it's necessary but because I think it's sufficient, and perhaps those who want a notice will think so, too.)